# Trying to track scroll gesture in NSView

Tags: xcode, gesture, nsview

I have seen people say to use:

```
(void)touchesMovedWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event
```

or

```
(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event
```

to detect the two fingers down on the trackpad. While these do work, what I need specifically is some value associated with the events so I can move my `NSScrollers` programmatically. The `deltaX` and `deltaY` values of theEvent (event) are `0` when I move two fingers across the touchpad.